# Where to add --trusted-host option to pip in Puppet/Vagrant?

Tags: proxy, vagrant, pip, puppet

I have a Mediawiki Vagrant box that works perfectly at home, but not at work since we are behind an infamous web proxy that decrypts HTTPS+SSL traffic with a "man in the middle attack", so all certificate checks made by Vagrant and/or the box fail.

So I have to remove all authentication from my project ( https://github.com/goulu/mediawiki ). I could already solve problems related to vagrant plugins and ruby gems, but now I'm stuck with an error from pip :

```
DEBUG ssh: stderr: Error:
Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/pip install -q git-review==1.24'
returned 1:   Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement git-review==1.24
```

I tried to edit .\puppet\modules\git\manifests\init.pp by adding [install_options](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#package-providers) as below but it doesn't help:

```
package { 'git-review':
    ensure   => '1.24',
    provider => 'pip',
    install_options => ['--trusted-host pypi.python.org'],
}
```

is it the correct place to add this option ? 
Alternatively, how can I add a pip.conf file to my project ?
Or should I edit this line in .\puppet\modules\mwv\manifests\init.pp ?

```
package { 'python-pip': } -> Package <| provider == pip |>
```